# How to convert array pointer into an array argument from template function?

Tags: c++, templates

I guess the title is quite confusing, I'll explain my case with some code.

```
template<uint16_t Len>
void add(const int8_t (&i_array)[Len])
{
  // Do something
}

class Test
{
public:
int8_t* GetName()
{
  return name;
} 

private:
 int8_t name[10] = "myname";
}

int main()
{
 Test mytest;

 add(mytest.GetName()); // Compilation error
}
```

This code does not compile. The following error is generated : 
"Error#304 : no instance of function template add matches the argument list"

It seems that the compilator is not able to determine that GetName() return an array of size 10. Is that right ?

How could I call "add" with a pointer on an array ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test::GetName` returns a pointer, not an array. You cannot bind its result to a function that expects an array reference. However, you could change the signature of `GetName` to make it return the array (by reference, of course):

```
int8_t (&GetName())[10] { return name; }
```

Alternatively you could use a cast, but that would defeat the purpose of the type system.

Comment: Nice, I'll try it now.

Comment: BTW, I suggest to use a `typedef` to have a simpler syntax.